# How to downgrade macOS from a beta whilst retaining all data without prior backup

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I stupidly have lost my hard drive which contained a backup of my Mac when it was on macOS Monterey. I'm currently on the latest version of macOS Ventura and would like to downgrade.

I can make a backup now but it would be from macOS Ventura is there anyway I can use that for the latest version of macOS Monterey?

Comment: @MarcWilson - already mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a beta, the best we can say is "nobody knows".
The chances are you'll get most of it back but will lose any data that has changed structure, as such is Mail is likely to do at many OS boundaries. The rest you will have to pick out piecemeal, as there's no Migration/Time Machine method that will let you go 'downhill'.